# Why does dilithium have a longer bond length than dihydrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, orbitals

I've tried MO theory however they both have a bond order of 1. Which means we can not relate the bond order to the bond length.

[image]

[image]

My thinking -

I think that the h2 bond length is shorter due to only the 1s electrons participating in the bonding. Where as in dilithum we have the 2s electrons participating only. This makes me think that due to Li having a filled 1s subshell, as the 2 atoms approach the 2s electrons are repelled by the other atoms 1s electrons. Once bonded the filled inner core of 1s electrons will repel the other atoms 2s electrons keeping the atoms at a further distance.

**I may be wrong any help would be great!**

Comment: Perhaps the size of the atoms involved already gives you a hint : the lithium atom is much larger than the hydrogen atom, about 2.5 times.

Comment: Also, consider electron shielding, https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introductory_Chemistry_(CK-12)/06%3A_The_Periodic_Table/6.17%3A_Electron_Shielding .

Comment: Pallas gave a hint. Even more extreme is the comparison between a proton and a lithium ion! Your mention of electron repulsion also hints at possible 2p contributions, which are energetically closer to 2s than to 1s. So the bond length could be longer without being weaker.